# How can I turn a quad into a semi-circle?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a quad with a custom Shader that creates an AR "Portal" to a 360 picture. I'm looking at turning the quad portal it into a semi-circle shape instead of a rectangle but can't work out how.

I've tried a couple scripts that I've found online but had no result.  Any help is much appreciated. Pretty new to Unity so please excuse my inability to do simple things like create a semi-circle.

edit:

Trying to turn the shape of this quad from a rectangle into a semi-circle.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a few screenshots please? It's not very clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @Eugenio added a screenshot. It's just a quad with a custom shader.

Comment: So you want to change the quad into half a circle or an ellipse?

Comment: @Eugenio half a circle please

Comment: I feel like your best bet and the easiest way (without programming in some sort of shape) would be to just model one out by yourself in a modelling program. If you have some experience in Blender this is quite an easy task. Probably someone has a better answer though, just wait

Comment: @Eugenio cheers, I'll give that a shot

Comment: By the way, maybe this article could help you achieve your goal: http://unitytipsandtricks.blogspot.it/2013/08/procedural-meshes-circles.html
Have fun, cheers!